# Convert correlated and join SQL query to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

Please consider this Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(fld_09 + fld_10), fld_Switch, fld_Area
FROM   Mytbl t
WHERE  fld_Year = 2000
   AND fld_Month = 1
   AND fld_02 != '04'
   AND fld_Switch = 2
   AND (
           (fld_09 + fld_10) NOT IN 
                (SELECT DISTINCT(fld_09 + fld_10)
                 FROM  Mytbl q
                 WHERE  fld_Year = 2000
                 AND fld_Month = 1
                 AND fld_02 != '04'
                 AND fld_Switch = 1
                 AND t.fld_Area = q.fld_Area)
       )
GROUP BY fld_Area, fld_09, fld_10, fld_Switch
```

this query execute in 1 second.I want to write this query with linq.I wrote this code:

```
var subQuery= (from r in ent.Mytbl 
               where r.fld_Year == Year &&
                     r.fld_Month == Month &&
                     r.fld_Switch == 1 &&
                     r.fld_02 != "04"
               select r.fld_09 + r.fld_10;

var query = (from o in ent.Mytbl 
             let code = o.fld_09 + o.fld_10
             where o.fld_Year == Year &&
                   o.fld_Month == Month &&
                   o.fld_Switch == 2 &&
                   o.fld_F02 != "04" &&
                   subQuery.Contains(code) == false
             group o by new { o.fld_Area, o.fld_09, o.fld_10, o.fld_Switch }
             into gr
             select new
             {
                 a = gr.Key.fld_09 + gr.Key.fld_10,
                 gr.Key.fld_Area,c=gr.Count()
             }).Distinct();
```

Are this 2 query equal?

Second query take 2 minutes when execute. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You can inspect the SQL emitted by your LINQ query which is the only real way to compare them. If the results are the same then of course they are in some way equivalent but there's no guarantee the performance will be the same, LINQ to SQL may not optimize the query as well as you do when you write it yourself.

Comment: Just keep the current SQL query in a stored procedure, it is not the end of the world, even if the rest of your app is entirely entity framework and linq

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to tweak this query, if you aren't already. I believe the `let` clause is your performance hit.